# How to compare the relative pass/fail rates between different sample sizes?

Tags: small-sample, contingency-tables, mean

I have a table as follows:

`Country 1   Country 2   Country 3
Cohort  809         7           9
Passed  755         5           8
Failed  54          2           1`

I would like to generate the relative fails rates by country, but accounting in some way for the significant differences in sample size. I feel like from my rudimentary maths knowledge that I should use a [contingency table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contingency_table) but I don't know:

- a) If this is correct.
- b) How to go about it if it is.

Note: I have more countries than what is represented here (this is all that would fit), but they are of similarly disparate sample sizes.

If you could guide me in the right direction in layman terms, I would very much appreciate it.